# .Net core console application - DI for the Program class?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have a .Net core 2 console application and the following code in the root `Program` class shows how the NLog is configured for DI.

```
private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory().AddConsole(LogLevel.Information).AddDebug().AddNLog();
    loggerFactory.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config");
    services.AddSingleton(loggerFactory);
    services.AddLogging();
```

However, I also need to use the logger in the `Program` class. Right now I just add a line in the `ConfigureServices` to initialize the `_logger` member.

```
_logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();
```

Is there any other way?

Comment: Any context where/what you want to log in `Program` ? :)

Comment: Some error or exception.